# log all trace info during a debug session in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, tcl, trace

I would like to log all the debug information on each step (to crunch all these data later) of a debugging session, such as the name of the method called, the parameter value, all the variables values, etc.

Is there any option that enables this? Where should I change the code to make this happen?

One important thing: it isn't a java program. It's a TCL being run from inside eclipse, using activeState debugger. So AOP and JDT are not options here :-(

TIA

Leo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use the [`trace`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/trace.htm) command in tcl.

A simple example:

```
set ::TraceFd [open {/path/to/logfile} a]
proc ::TraceLog args {
    puts $::TraceFd $args
}
trace add execution source {enterstep leavestep} ::TraceLog
source /the/main/file.tcl
```

This does more or less what you want. I don't have any idea how eclipse works with Tcl, but the best way to debug Tcl is with Tcl :)

Comment: +1. Note that execution tracing has a heavy performance penalty, especially in code that is otherwise designed for at least some speed. It might be a penalty worth paying in some cases, but you *do* pay. (You also won't get tracing into any sub-interpreters, if the code creates any of them. Most Tcl code doesn't.)

Comment: just one more thing (trace is good enough, but maybe we can do it better). Is there a way to make trace show only the rows effectively executed? (ignoring for example whole "if" loops where the conditional was't met). TIA

Comment: if a line is not executed, then it will not show up. But if `if 0 {foo bar}` is executed, the entire `if 0 {foo bar}` goes into the log, `foo bar` not.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact needs, maybe have a look at the logger package and its trace Loglevel too, it also uses execution traces to gather some info.

http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/logger.html

You can add them to your code, and if they are switched off you pay zero performance penalty and you can switch them on when needed.