# TCL Code Debugger/Stepper

Tags: debugging, tcl

I was wondering if there were any somewhat "current" tools that allow me to debug or step through my running code. All the programs that I've found are heavily deprecated and/or don't work with TCL 8.6.

EDIT: To be more clear, here is exactly what I need:

I need a tool that lets me see which line of code is executing at what time. My error is coming from an external hardware source, and I need to see what line of code is being executed when the hardware fails.

Comment: The best I've found so far is ramdebugger but I think you may have tried that. One trick I sometimes do is attach tkcon to a running program (if it's a Tk program it's easy). Then in tkcon I can edit functions, call functions edit global variables etc.

Comment: That's just a console window right?

Comment: Yes. But it implements a really useful edit command. For example you can type `edit variablename` and it will open the value of that variable in an editor window. Or `edit procname` and it will open the definition of the proc in an editor window. Basically, you can insert puts inside functions in running programs.

Comment: While that's not exactly what I need it to do, that's still really useful. Thank you. Edit: I can't use the `edit` command. it says `invalid command name`. Is there something I have to source?

Comment: Afaik, ActiveState has a commercial Tcl debugger.

Comment: I've tried installing Tcl DevKit, but the installation fails.

Comment: You don't have to source anything, you should be able to just start `tkcon` and use commands like `edit`, `idebug`, `observe` et al. Have a look at the commands [here](http://tkcon.sourceforge.net/docs/procs.html).

Comment: How do attach tkcon to my program?

Comment: Most of us are a little stumped here, I think, because Tcl programming mostly doesn't require structured debugging tools like that. Tcl has been my main language for over 15 years now; currently I work with data extraction / analysis using tools of my own making, and to tell you the truth I seldom do real debugging, (I do use the testing tools religiously, though.) Tcl is a different language in many ways: its introspection tools and the ease with which one can remould, remodel, and reshape code on the fly make debugging less crucial.

Comment: If you've got a problem with TclDevKit installation, _definitely_ contact ActiveState's support. It's a commercial product and that's exactly what I'd use their support process for.

Comment: @PeterLewerin - I suppose the primary reason for my confusion is that I was trained with mostly compiled OOP languages, Java and C++. The whole concept of editing code during run-time is foreign for me, and I haven't had much practice with the tools that you've mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You could try tracing command execution, as described in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15534031/301832). It'll have quite a bit of performance impact, but it can generate a detailed log of exactly what was going on. Since you'd be looking for something related to hardware problems, you might also want to use `fconfigure` to switch the output buffering to `line` (or `none`; the difference doesn't matter if you only write complete lines).

Another way to look for hardware problems *when running on Linux* is to try running with [`strace`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace). That logs what's going on with system calls, which can be very useful. If you're looking at the log, be aware that Tcl's implementation calls `gettimeofday()` a lot when using the event loop; it's expected, correct behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This is no place for tutorialing, but I really recommend that you take a look at the introspection and examination tools that `tkcon` offers. A simplistic and very short example: you have launched some code from `tkcon`, code that includes the obscure and intricate command `foo`. You suspect something is up with it, so you enter the command `edit -type proc foo` and get a window with the text

```
proc foo {} {
    for {set i 0} {$i < 10} {incr i} {
        set a [expr {2*$i}]
    }
}
```

You decide to keep track of changes to `a` and enter `observe variable a write` as a new first command in the body. Then you choose `Send to slave` in the `Send to...` menu, which means that `foo` is now redefined in the main `tkcon` window. When you run your code again, the changes to `a` will be logged to the `tkcon` console window (in the form of `set a ...` command strings).

Going back to the editing window, you can add a breakpoint by inserting the command `idebug break`. If you enter the command `idebug on` in the console window and run your code again, execution will halt at this point and you get an interactive prompt where you can e.g. climb/descend the call stack, list variables, and get a stack trace, and also execute arbitrary commands to change variable values etc.

If you've made significant changes to the command in the editing window, you can save it to a new file or append it to an old one (a Tcl source file can have several definitions of the same command: only the last one is used). If you don't save it, the original source is unchanged. You can even have several editing windows open with the same command and edit them separately, trying different variants.

You can also source `tkcon` into your own code and use `tkcon show` to get a console window that knows the state of your program.

Entering the command `edit -type file $argv0` in the console should let you have a look at the source for `tkcon`, the ultimate documentation.